# SQL Server query to filter the financial year when month and year are in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've attached the sample data. Here actually I wanted to calculate the running total of emp_contribution and vpf column together. however that should be bounded within a financial year. suppose for 2015 it will start from April, 2015 to March, 2016. This is where I'm facing the challenges.

Below I've attached my attempt query but under the where clause filter is not working perfectly

```
select  
    case when sum(isnull(emp_contribution,0)) over(partition by emp_no order by pcm_month) + sum(isnull(vpf,0)) over(partition by emp_no order by pcm_month) < 3000 
        then sum(isnull(emp_contribution,0)) over(partition by emp_no order by pcm_month) + sum(isnull(vpf,0)) over(partition by emp_no order by pcm_month)
        else null
   end empcontbtnwithouttax,
   case 
       when sum(isnull(emp_contribution,0)) over(partition by emp_no order by pcm_month) + sum(isnull(vpf,0)) over(partition by emp_no order by pcm_month) >= 3000
           then sum(isnull(emp_contribution,0)) over(partition by emp_no order by pcm_month) + sum(isnull(vpf,0)) over(partition by emp_no order by pcm_month)
           else null
    end empcontbtnwithtax,
    pcm_month, pcm_year, emp_no 
from 
    [dbo].[pf_contribution_master]
where 
    (pcm_year >= 2015 and pcm_month >= 4 )
    and (pcm_year <= 2016 and pcm_month < 4 )
    and emp_no= 11101201 
order by 
    pcm_year, pcm_month
```

[image]

Comment: `(pcm_year >= 2015 and pcm_month >= 4 )` is "if the year is 2015 **or 2016** and the month is April or later". `(pcm_year <= 2016 and pcm_month < 4 )` is "if the year is **2015 or** 2016 and the month is prior to April". See the problem?

Comment: @HABO I've tried that but getting more number of records as repetitively. Which was not working for me.

Comment: I was explaining the issue with _your_ code. (You've accepted an answer without knowing _why_ your code wasn't working.) What you want is something more like `( ( pcm_year = 2015 and pcm_month >= 4 ) or ( pcm_year = 2016 and pcm_month < 4 ) ) and emp_no= 11101201;`. Note that this logic does not extend gracefully to years that are not adjacent, e.g. `( ( pcm_year = 2010 and pcm_month >= 4 ) or ( 2010 < pcm_year and pcm_year < 2020 ) or ( pcm_year = 2020 and pcm_month < 4 ) ) and emp_no= 11101201;` to handle the intervening years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual reason for the unexpected results in this specific case is the `(pcm_year >= 2015 and pcm_month >= 4) and (pcm_year <= 2016 and pcm_month < 4)` part of the `WHERE` clause, where the use of the second `AND` operator is wrong.

In this situation, you may consider an additional calculation and a different `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE 
   (pcm_year * 100 + pcm_month >= 201504) AND
   (pcm_year * 100 + pcm_month < 201604) AND
   (emp_no = 11101201)
...
```

Comment: A vague enough edit. Is there any particular `and` of the three that might be problematic?

Comment: Are you suggesting that `(pcm_year >= 2015 and pcm_month >= 4) OR (pcm_year <= 2016 and pcm_month < 4)`, which would allow some data from _any_ year, would fix the OP's problem? Or is there some other operator you would replace the second `AND` with? Aside: If performance is an issue then a _persisted computed column_ could be added for `pcm_year * 100 + pcm_month` and indexed.

Comment: @HABO, of course no. Replacing second `AND` with `OR` is not a general solution.